# Convert Blog to PDF or Epub Book

Tags: pdf, conversion, epub

I want a command or script to collect all the posts on a given blog and convert them into a PDF and/or Epub book without needing to be the owner of the blog. This [website](http://blog2book.pothi.com/) allows users to convert blogs to PDF without needing to be the blog owner, but it will only convert up to 100 posts. Most of the blogs I want to convert have 200+ posts. I'd like the published date of the posts be included at the top or bottom of each post, and graphics and images retained if possible.

Answer (score 1):

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ should satisfy your HTML to PDF conversion needs. It can combine multiple input files and they can be on the web too.